# Go to external url?

Tags: html, anchor

Okay, this is so simple yet I don't know how to do it.

I use `vhost` that makes `localhost/wamp/www/blog/public` become `blog.dev`

sample:

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

expected result: go to `stackoverflow.com`

what it actually does: go to `blog.dev/stackoverflow.com`

So, how should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, if you use a relative URL like above, your browser will assime that it's a URL relative to the URL you're currently browsing. That's why

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com">
```

links to **blog.dev/stackoverflow.com**

Replace

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com">
```

with the absolute URL

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
```

to get what you need.

Secondly, you could add **target** attribute to your URL if you want to open the link in a new window/tab:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
```